# Setting $PATH for gcloud installation

Tags: python, bash, gcloud

I am trying to set up gcloud and although I followed the instructions, I keep getting `gcloud: command not found`

I have read so many answers and have tried everything.

I believe the issue is with my path.

After trying to manually set my path with `export $PATH=/ACTUAL-PATH/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc:$PATH`

I kept getting `<path> not a valid identifier`

So i read about debugging my PATH and after entering `echo "$PATH"` this is what i got.

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

how do i fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export PATH=...$PATH` (without the dollar to start with)?

Comment: i tried that. it look like the path worked (See below) but gcloud is still not working.. `echo "$PATH"
/Users/PATH/dev/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
MacBook-Pro:dev D$ gcloud init
-bash: gcloud: command not found
`